# AngularJS ng-model with collections

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui

Newbie question.

I have a model defined like this:

```
 $scope.model = some json like below:

"ApplicantNames":[
  "Primary applicant : Ian Vink",
  "Joint applicant : Sally Ride"
]
```

I have 2 input boxes , one for each applicant, that I wish to bind via ng-model, but I don't know the naming structure

```
 <input ng-model="model.ApplicantNames[0]????">
 <input ng-model="model.ApplicantNames[1]????">
```

Note these are actually complex Kendo controls bound in MVC so I am not using  ng-looping to create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct.

If you want to bind to the elements of `$scope.model.ApplicantNames` and be able to edit them in the view, the "naming structure" is:

```
<input ng-model="model.ApplicantNames[0]" />
<input ng-model="model.ApplicantNames[1]" />
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fZ7Zp/)**.